# You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql

Выдает такую ошибку:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ')' at line 15

```
<?php
// Функция save (сохранить в базу новый товар)
function save($author, $title, $pubyear, $price) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(
                    author,
                    title,
                    pubyear,
                    price
                ) VALUES(
                    '$author',
                    '$title',
                    $pubyear,
                    $price                  
                )";
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

// Вывод всего из каталога
function selectAll() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    return $result;
}

// Добавление товаров в корзину
function add2basket($customer, $goodsid, $quantity, $datetime) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO basket(
                customer,
                goodsid,
                quantity,
                datetime
            ) VALUES(
                '$customer',
                $goodsid,
                $quantity,
                $datetime               
            )";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

// Вывод корзины пользователя
function myBasket() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog, basket 
        WHERE customer='".session_id()."' 
        and catalog.id=basket.goodsid";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    return $result;
}

// Удаление товара из корзины
function basketDel($id){
    $sql = "DELETE FROM basket WHERE id = $id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

// Пересохранение товаров из корзины в заказы
function resave($datetime) {
    $goods = myBasket();
    while ($good = mysql_fetch_assoc($goods)) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(
                    author,
                    title,
                    pubyear,
                    price,
                    customer,
                    quantity,
                    datetime
                ) VALUES(
                    '" . $good["author"] . "',
                    '" . $good["title"] . "',
                    " . $good["pubyear"] . ",
                    " . $good["price"] . ",
                    '" . $good["customer"] . "',
                    " . $good["quantity"] . ", $datetime)";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            
    }
    // Удаление данных из таблицы basket
    $sql = "DELETE FROM basket WHERE customer='" . session_id() . "'";  
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}

// Получение информации о заказах
function getOrders() {
    // Получение заказчиков из log-файла 
    $orders = file(ORDERS_LOG);
    
    $allorders = array();
    
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        list($name, $email, $phone, $address, $customer, $date) = explode("|", $order);
        
        $orderinfo = array();
        
        $orderinfo["name"] = $name; 
        $orderinfo["email"] = $email;   
        $orderinfo["phone"] = $phone;   
        $orderinfo["address"] = $address;   
        $orderinfo["customer"] = $customer; 
        $orderinfo["date"] = $date; 
        // Товары из заказов:
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders 
            WHERE customer='".$orderinfo["customer"]."' AND datetime=".$orderinfo["date"];
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
        $orderinfo["goods"] = $result;
        $allorders[] = $orderinfo;
    }
    return $allorders;
}
```

?>

Answer (score 1):

```
 " . $good["quantity"] . ", '$datetime')";
```

Дату в кавычки. В pdo или mysqli такой проблемы не возникло бы.